# ios - How to improve draw and update large image performance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-image

I'm developing a selective color app in iOS (There are many similar apps in App Store, example: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/color-splash/id304871603?mt=8). My idea is simple: use two UIViews, one for foreground (black and white image) and one for background (color image). I use touchesBegan, touchesMoved and so on events to track user input in foreground. In touches moved, I use kCGBlendModeClear to erase a path that the user moved the finger. Finally, I combine two images in UIViews together to get the result. The result will be displayed in the foreground view.

To achieve that idea, I have written two different implements.They work well with small image but very slow with large image (> 3MB).

In first version, I use two UIImageViews (imgForegroundView and imgBackgroundView). 
Here is code to get the image result when user moved finger from point p1 to point p2. This code will be called from touchesMoved event:

```
-(UIImage*)getImageWithPoint:(CGPoint)p1 andPoint:(CGPoint)p2{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImg.size);

[self.imgForegroundView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImg.size.width, originalImg.size.height)];

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, TRUE);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushSize);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1.0);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, p1.x, p1.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p2.x, p2.y);

CGContextStrokePath(context);

UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return result;   
}
```

After get image result, I replace imgForegroundView.image with it.

In version 2, I use idea in http://www.effectiveui.com/blog/2011/12/02/how-to-build-a-simple-painting-app-for-ios/. The background is still UIImageView but the foreground is a subclass of UIView. In foreground, I use a cache context to store image. When user move finger, I draw on cache context, then I update the view by override drawRect method. In drawRect method, I get image from cache context and draw it to current context.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGImageRef cacheImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cacheContext);
CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cacheImage);
CGImageRelease(cacheImage);
}
```

Then, in same way with first version, I get image from foreground and combine it with background.

With small image (<= 2 MB), both versions work well. But with larger image, it is very terrible: after user moves finger a long times (3 - 5 seconds, depend on image size), the image will be updated.
I want my app can achieve the speed near real time such as example app above, but I don't know how to do. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Here your are referent https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173

Comment: Apple has a very good WWDC video on something very similar - look for titles about drawing efficiently. ... And use Instruments to figure out where the inefficiency is. Don't ask us. Don't guess. Use Instruments.

Comment: @phuongle: I want to preserve the original size of image so that I do not resize the image.

Comment: @matt: I have used Instruments, but I can't find the problem.